# Remove Parent Key from nested Object

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to sort an object and then create a new object with the sorted data. But the problem is, whenever i push the data to an empty array, it creates a new object with parent keys 0,1,2...

```
{
    "0": {
        "note-1502256197947": {
            "content": "If that doesn't work, then it will reload the entire page.",
            "fav": true,
            "last_modified": "",
            "publish_date": 1502256197947,
            "slug": "starred-note",
            "title": "Starred Note"
        }
    },
    "1": {
        "note-1502108241905": {
            "categories": {
                "Learn": true,
                "Wordpress": true
            },
            "content": "Creating a embed several routes to handle Creation, Retrieval",
            "fav": true,
            "last_modified": "",
            "publish_date": 1502108241905,
            "slug": "a-new-title",
            "title": "A New Title"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I am trying to sort the object:

```
      var noteref = firebase.database().ref(`noted${uid}/notes/`);
      var sortedKeys = [];

      noteref.orderByChild('fav').once("value", function(snapshot) {

          snapshot.forEach(function(child) {

              sortedKeys.unshift({[child.key]:child.val()}); 
              //sortedKeys[child.key] = child.val();  ***Works! but the order is lost
          });

          var newObject = {...sortedKeys};
          console.log(newObject);
      });
```

This how I am trying to recreate the Object:

```
{
  "note-1502256197947": {
            "content": "If that doesn't work, then it will reload the entire page.",
            "fav": true,
            "last_modified": "",
            "publish_date": 1502256197947,
            "slug": "starred-note",
            "title": "Starred Note"

  },
  "note-1502108241905": {
            "categories": {
                "Learn": true,
                "Wordpress": true
            },
            "content": "Creating a embed several routes to handle Creation, Retrieval",
            "fav": true,
            "last_modified": "",
            "publish_date": 1502108241905,
            "slug": "a-new-title",
            "title": "A New Title"
  }

}
```

Comment: I didn't read your code, but that's how Firebase automatically handles arrays, so I'm guessing you're trying to push an array of objects in there instead of a single object.

Comment: I am actually pushing a single object with react rebase syncstate. In react state the object is saved  without the 0,1,2.. parent keys.

Comment: Firebase doesn't natively store arrays. It instead stores the values in regular JavaScript objects with sequential, numeric keys. Then when you read the data back, the SDK converts it into an array again. See https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing some concepts of object. If an object has couple of properties then it does not mean the are sorted in any manner.

```
  {
   "note-1502256197947": {...
             },
   "note-1502108241905": {...
             }
}
```

Suppose this is an object. This object has 2 properties **note-1502256197947** and **note-1502108241905** . It does not mean that they are sorted.

Answer (score -1):

if you want object formatted data mean then why are pushing value into array?
then its better to thing before making a format in foreach,

there could be two way of formatting:
 1. create one empty object and make format as expected like below:
 snapshot.forEach(function(child) {

```
          sortedKeys[child.key] = child.val(); 
      });
```

2. and as you now following

Note: make sure data from api and inside foreach is comming or not by debugging

Comment: I already tried that. Please check my code again for the commented code. This way, foreach order is lost.the object items are being pushed in random order.